# How to compare text in sql

Tags: sql

I am trying to find the 1st country, alphabetically, in a continent

When I write the below query, I don't get a result,

```
SELECT continent, country_name
FROM world 
WHERE country_name = ALL(SELECT country_name
                         FROM world)
```

However, when I add the '<=' operator instead, I get a result back (Asia, Afghanistan). Why is that? i.e neither the '=' nor the '<' operators gave me back a result, however, when I combined them both, i.e '<=' I got back a result

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the first country alphabetically for each continent ?

You can do that :

```
SELECT continent, MIN(country_name) AS country_name
FROM world 
GROUP BY continent
```